# How can I add an Sql Query in the middle of HTML code?

Tags: php, session, authentication, system

I want to make a login system, where the user can see all the messages he has received. In my database the `insurance_company` is the username and that is what I want it to show by. Here is my code. How do I fix it?
- Thanks Prem

```
<?php

  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM claims WHERE insurance_company = $_SESSION['user']";


  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    echo $row['Claim'] . "<br />";

    }


?>
```

Comment: Regardless, your code suffers from syntax errors. I recommend you throw away Notepad and start using an IDE like PhpStorm or Netbeans

Comment: :facepalm: the mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP, use the mysqli_* functions instead or PDO. Appending the username like that is probably vulnerable to SQL injection. Are you calling `session_start()`? Did you connect to the DB first? Do you have a login system built so `$_SESSION['user']` contains the user? Make sure to check it's set first before attempting to try to use it. Before outputting data from a database, make sure to escape it: htmlentities. Apparently you need to build a login system first. There's lots of already-existing code out there for a login system. Google it.

Comment: @Ultimater Ya, I have the login system and there is a variable 'user'. The login works and takes me to the right page where Hello world is echoed. But when I try to run this sql query it doesn't work. For SQL injection, I have stripped the tags and slashes and all of those things so I think I should be fine, unless I need to change something?

Comment: You forgot to quote the user in the query. You should always check the query ran successfully before trying to use its results: `if($rs)` if it didn't you can see the error: `mysql_error()`. Also you should check `mysql_num_rows()` before looping. Once you've fixed the error, please switch over to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP code can be written anywhere in HTML code. You need to just place your PHP code between  tags. As you can see in the example bellow I have used php code between p tags.

```
<?php
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM claims WHERE insurance_company = $_SESSION['user']";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {?>

        <p> <?php echo $row['Claim'] . "<br />"; ?> <p>

    <?php }
?>
```

Comment: Here is the error code I get when I tried to use your code;

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Answer (score -2):

If you want it to show `insurance_company`, you must `echo` this value in the response array:

```
echo $row['insurance_company']
```

Comment: I think that _"that is what I want it to show by"_ means that he want to base his query on the name, not just echo it.

Comment: He already knows the insurance company if it's part of his query. Plus you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: insurance_company is a column in the DataBase.